# Invalid block tag on line 18: 'endblock', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock extra_js'

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm getting the following error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /open_trades/ Invalid block tag on line 18:
>   'endblock', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock extra_js'. Did you forget
>   to register or load this tag?

The following piece of code gives this error:

```
{% block extra_js %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = {{ cryptos }};
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
</script>
{% endblock extra_js %}
```

This template file extends base.html, which contains the following line in the head tag:

```
{% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}
```

I've checked the other questions on here regarding this type of error, but all of those involved some kind of typo. I've retyped the entire thing, including the {% extends "base.html" %}.

I've also checked that my Python code definitely includes the list variable called *cryptos* in the context variables.

What else can I try to fix this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Which is line 18?

Comment: Line 18 is {% endblock extra_js %}

Comment: That is very weird. Can you try just `{% endblock %}`?

Comment: Just tried it, I don't understand why that changed anything but it works now.

Answer (score -2):

The template tag may be used more than once in the same template file. I've done that before and I spent 30 minutes working it out.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?